# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 12

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
2 warnings generated.
/Users/hongziqing/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.4/ios/Classes/FLTI
magePickerPlugin.m:149:20: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView
is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil)
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulat
or14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has
been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIAlertView : UIView
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/hongziqing/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.4/ios/Classes/FLTI
magePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:17:44: warning: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Will be removed in a future release, use PHPicker. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulat
or14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIImagePickerController.h:62:51: note:
'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
UIKIT_EXTERN UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey const UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL API_DEPRECATED("Will
be removed in a future release, use PHPicker.", ios(4.1, 11.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos); // an NSURL that
references an asset in the AssetsLibrary framework
^
/Users/hongziqing/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.4/ios/Classes/FLTI
magePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:21:47: warning: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 11 - Will be removed in a future release [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[ referenceURL ]
^
In module 'Photos' imported from
/Users/hongziqing/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.4/ios/Classes/FLTI
magePickerPhotoAssetUtil.h:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulat
or14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHAsset.h:74:1: note:
'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
+ (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable
PHFetchOptions *)options API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a future release", ios(8, 11), tvos(8, 11))
API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
^
2 warnings generated.
/Users/hongziqing/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-7.0.3/ios/Classes/Geoloc
atorPlugin.m:199:11: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
^~~~~~~
openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Target Support Files/geolocator/geolocator-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulat
or14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:123:1: note: 'openURL:' has
been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0,
10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/AppEvents/FBSDKAppEvents.m:463:48: warning: cast to smaller
integer type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') from 'id _Nullable' [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
isImplicitlyLogged:(BOOL)parameters[FBSDKAppEventParameterImplicitlyLogged]
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
2021-07-09 05:19:21.827 ibtoold[20060:1048314] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
TMPDIR = "/var/folders/g3/5c3p3dks7j98vrqf5drj5tb00000gn/T/A091F85B-23E9-46EF-8E4B-4A482DCD63E5";
}
/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/R
unner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set
"AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/R
unner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set
"AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/R
unner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only
apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/build
/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/build
/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/build
/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car
/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Intermedia
tes.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

```
/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Intermedia
tes.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-F061639FB3B01BBD0F33B92D.sh: line 2:
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/uni_links/uni_links.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/sqflite/sqflite.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/location/location.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/image_cropper/image_cropper.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/image_picker/image_picker.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/url_launcher/url_launcher.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods_Runner.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/hongziqing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gmsrxwgtttvwtneuagslajhemjwt/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/geolocator/geolocator.framework'

/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target
'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from
project 'Pods')
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FBSDKLoginKit'
from project 'Pods')
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FBSDKCoreKit'
from project 'Pods')
/Users/hongziqing/Desktop/APP_code/Development-Of-Auxiliary-Software-For-Medical-Scooter/Flutter_app/ios/P
ods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from
project 'Pods')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.

Answer (score 1):

The errors tell you that your iOS deployment target is not supported (most likely due to dependencies requiring a higher iOS version)

You need to set the minimum iOS deployment target to version XX.xx

Change / add this line at the top of the Podfile file located in `[YOUR-APP-DIRECTORY]/ios/Podfile`

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
```